# Error in Jasmine Test in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

i want to test functions in angular js using jasmine. i have created one controller in which one scope function which is given below.

```
  app.controller('NavigationCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $route, $rootScope) {
    $scope.title="Hello World";     

   $scope.testMe = function () {
        $scope.title = "Welcome";
    }

}]);
```

Also, i want to call above controller function i.e $scope.testMe from another controller using jasmine test case. so, i create another controller and try to call functions from this controller.

```
   app.controller('RunTestCaseCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route', '$routeParams', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'MDT_Constant', function ($scope, $http, $location, $route, $routeParams, $rootScope, $timeout, MDT_Constant) {

    describe('mycontroller', function () {
        beforeEach(module('app'));
        it('scopeTestSpec',
            inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
                var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                $controller('NavigationCtrl', {
                    $scope: $scope
                });
                $controller.testMe(); 
                expect($scope.title).toEqual('Welcome');
                console.log('ok');
            }));
    });
}]);
```

this will give the error "module is not defined".

so, how can i call controller method from another controller using jasmine test

Comment: Have you referenced angular.mock ?

Comment: Add a reference to angular.mocks.js in your page and try again

Comment: yes i already added reference of angular.mocks.js

Comment: I don't think that describe block to be placed inside controller ?

Comment: i do not want to create new page for jasmine test so i just create new controller and run all the test cases from that controller.